# NSXMLElement undefined?

Tags: xml, ios

I am trying to use `NSXMLElement` to build an XML document in my app, but when i build i get an error which reads "NSXMLElement undelcared".

From what i can tell, `NSXMLElement` is part of the Foundation Framework, and should therefore be included with the rest of the framework with the line `#include <Foundation/foundation.h>.` Is this class not available for iOS(4.2)? Is there some other class that i can use?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure NSXMLElement (at least currently - 4.2) isn't available under iOS.

From the "Migrating from Cocoa" section of the [iOS Technology Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/PortingfromCocoa/PortingfromCocoa.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898-CH8-SW10) docs:

> The Foundation framework provides
>   support for XML parsing through the
>   NSXMLParser class. However, other XML
>   parsing classes (including
>   NSXMLDocument, NSXMLNode, and
>   NSXMLElement) are not available in
>   iOS. In addition to the NSXMLParser
>   class, you can also use the libXML2
>   library, which provides a C-based XML
>   parsing interface.